# Calculating double ward times

Tags: microsoft-excel

My wife uses Excel to keep track of working hours of her team, but this is all manual work. Is there a way to let Excel calculate when more than 2 people are working in the same shift?

The tricky thing is that people's shift start at different hours but sometimes overlap.

The data looks as follows (there are many more employees, but this shows the general layout):

[image]

Comment: You should really start by putting each hour in separate cell, that way is much easier.

Comment: The problem is this is unfortunately generated by their HR departement.

Comment: This will most likely require vba to rip apart the data and normalize it so it can be mined.

Comment: Is it possible to use the Text to Columns, and use a space as a delimiter, to split that data? (I'm hoping the new lines are due to text wrapping, and not an new line character in the cell itself)

Comment: @BenjaminDiele why don't she just keep two sets of data? I think it would be possible to have a separate sheet with real data, and this one generated automatically (via `=(cell&' '&cell & CHAR(10) & cell ...)` - where CHAR(10) is a line break)

Comment: What **specifically** do you want as output ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest idea (also far from any optimization or code quality):

1) assume we can ignore the short break during (e.g. 10:00-14:00  14:15-18:00 is same as 10:00-18:00). I do this in variable **shift** by taking the first and last time in a cell (and remove the colon).

2) create an array of "minutes" in a day 1 to 2400 (so almost half of the array is not used at all)

3) for each "minute" calculate how many people were working

We add 1 to shift start - this way we don't count boundary overlaps (e.g. if "A" starts and "B" ends at 12:00 this will not be an overlap)

```
Function shiftOverlaps(r As Range) As Integer
    Dim shiftStart As Integer
    Dim shiftEnd As Integer
    Dim shift As String
    Dim wholeDay(1 To 2400) As Integer

    shiftOverlaps = 0        

    For Each c In r
        shift = Replace(Left(Trim(c.Value), 5) & " " & Right(Trim(c.Value), 5), ":", "")
        If shift <> " " Then
            shiftStart = Left(shift, 4) + 1
            shiftEnd = Right(shift, 4)
            For i = 1 To 2400
                If i >= shiftStart And i <= shiftEnd Then
                    wholeDay(i) = wholeDay(i) + 1
                    If wholeDay(i) > shiftOverlaps Then
                        shiftOverlaps = wholeDay(i)
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next c

    shiftOverlaps = shiftOverlaps - 1

End Function
```

[Result for your example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5l1i.png)